# Reading FCS files

Tags: python, file

I am working on flow cytometry.
I want to parse the .fcs files using python. I have researched on internet that there is a module `fcm` but that is for linux os and I am working on windows.

I want to know that how can I parse .fcs files in windows using python?
If anyone knows how can I use `fcm` in windows kindly let me know too.

Comment: You will have to install a C compiler. The installer will try msvc9 by default.

Comment: i have c compiler already. i want to know how can i parse .fcs files using python

Comment: If you try to install the fcm module using pip, the install process will try to compile the "C" parts using msvc9 on windows.

Comment: Does anybody know of an fcs reader API for Python 3? All the solution below seem to target Python 2.7 unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pyfcm does work on Windows. A tutorial for loading fcs files is at http://packages.python.org/fcm/basic.html. Installers are at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#py-fcm

Answer (score 3):

Check out [FlowPy](http://flowpy.wikidot.com/). The pre-requirements listed on its [download page](http://flowpy.wikidot.com/download-install) all link to Windows binaries. Seems to be a nice FCS GUI (and even non-GUI) project.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another python project for analysing flow cytometry data is FlowCytometryTools: http://gorelab.bitbucket.org/flowcytometrytools/

After python is set up with the required dependencies (matplotlib, pandas, etc.), this should work on any operating system.

Comment: Hi Eugene, on your install page you mentioned in the dependencies that "python 3.0 or higher are not yet supported!" Is that support around the corner? Do you know if any of the other alternative tools you list are capable of supporting Python 3? I think I've tried them all and found none being ported to 3.0. Thanks

Comment: We weren't planning on adding support for the time being. Is it at all possible for you to install python2.7 to work side by side? The only other tool with a python API I am aware of is pyfcm and I don't know whether it works with python 3.0+.

Comment: Thanks Eugene, I'm working on doing the upgrade via the source using 2to3 and am planning on communicating to you all the needed changes. So far its been pretty smooth, but I'm getting hung on the __init__.py imports to _ver and _doc which for some reason are struggling with the new relative path rules. Another fix was to change one import's syntax into `from .core import graph as graph`. Hopefully that's the last hurdle to build and hopefully it'll have a valid runtime as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am the maintainer of the FCM codebase, inherited after the original author graduated. FCM was developed to support an hierarchical Dirichlet process (HDP) clustering algorithm. I eventually decided to separate the functionality into 3 different libraries:

- [FlowIO](https://github.com/whitews/FlowIO): for those that simply need to read FCS data or create new FCS files
- [FlowUtils](https://github.com/whitews/FlowUtils): for performing basic flow functions (compensation & transforms)
- [FlowStats](https://github.com/whitews/FlowStats): for those looking to use the specific HDP clustering algorithm

In addition to these, we've recently started development on [FlowKit](https://github.com/whitews/FlowKit), which promises to be a more high-level and (hopefully) more intuitive Python framework for flow cytometry analysis and visualization, including GatingML support.

Note that both FlowIO and FlowUtils are on PyPI and available to install via pip, and both should be more compatible with all platforms including Windows, Mac, and Linux due to the reduced number of dependencies and recent bug fixes.