# freeform gating

Tags: python

I am working on flow cytometry. I am using fcs module of python for the same.
I want to create different gates for the created graph.

I am not able to understand how to create "freeform" gate.
kindly also let me know if anyone has any examples of freeform gating or any gating related to py-fcm.

here, i am interested in understanding how to get the area from freeform gating.

for reference.
http://packages.python.org/fcm/basic.html#gating-and-working-withe-the-view-tree

package
http://packages.python.org/fcm/basic.html

py-fcm
http://code.google.com/p/py-fcm/

Comment: Please help us by being more clear with your terms. What do you mean by "fcs"? What is the URL of a page describing the fcs module you are using? What are URLs of page describing "flow cytometry", and "freeform gates"? Please edit your question to add this information. It will help people answer you.

Comment: Are you using the FCM module mentioned in the answer your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13774315/212858)? If so, have you looked at the [gating documentation](http://packages.python.org/fcm/basic.html#gating-and-working-withe-the-view-tree)? If so, what problems did you have?

Comment: yes i did already but no idea of how to collect the points from freeform gating as they have also not implemented it

Answer (score 5):

A freeform gate is effectively a polygon gate with a vertex at every point that the mouse traveled while creating the gate. If you can create a polygon gate, then you can create a freeform gate; provided you have enough vertices. Since you also asked how to create other gate types, I suspect that your real question is how to perform gating.

To perform gating, you have to identify which events lie within a specified region. A rectangular region is the easiest to handle. Pseudocode to identify whether an event is in a rectangular region might look like:

```
EventInRectRegion (event e, region r)
    return (((e[r.xParam] >= r.xMin) && (e[r.xParam] < r.xMax)) &&
            ((e[r.yParam] >= r.yMin) && (e[r.yParam] < r.yMax)))
```

You should be able to see that determining whether an event is in a rectangle is the same type of code used to determine if any point is inside of any geometric shape. This type of code is used for mouse hit-testing and other related tasks.

Extending this to circles, polygons, and other shapes requires following the same path. Look at algorithms for things like [Point in Polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) for examples. For circles, you can either express the circle as a polygon and then use that algorithm, or you can find a point in circle algorithm instead.

I would expect that as you work on this further, you'll find performance to be a concern. The Point in Polygon article I linked shows several different algorithms where the primary concern is trading off performance for speed. You'll have to make some decisions about exactly how you want to perform this hit testing and what trade-offs you want to make.

For example, you can test each event exactly (as I've done in the pseudocode). This is accurate, but it will require that you evaluate the boundaries each time. An alternative algorithm is to pick a bitmap resolution and render the region within it. Then you can test whether an event is in the region by testing whether a given bitmap pixel is on or off. This allows you to only evaluate the region rendering math once, but at the cost of memory for the bitmaps and some precision in the hit testing.